# Ant taskdef resource absolute path on Windows

Tags: windows, ant, absolute-path

I am very new to ant, which I am probably about to make obvious.  I see a lot of discussion about how possible it is to use absolute paths in Windows, but I have not found a single example yet.

This thing used to work as a relative path, now I am trying to change it to an absolute path.

```
<taskdef resource="C:/dev/groovy-2.5.1/src/subprojects/groovy-ant/src/main/resources/org/codehaus/groovy/antlib.xml" />
```

This gives the following error message:
`Could not load definitions from resource C:/dev/groovy-2.5.1/src/subprojects/groovy-ant/src/main/resources/org/codehaus/groovy/antlib.xml. It could not be found.`

When I paste the path into windows explorer, it has no problem finding the xml file.  Please tell me what I am doing wrong?

**Edit**:  Thank you to those who are trying to help.  Please rest assured that I tried every combination of forward, backward, and double-backward slashes I could think of.  Also the /c/somedir as well as the c:/somedir format.

Can someone please post an example that is known to work?  I posted this question in the hope of ending the guesswork.  I've since worked-around the problem but I would love to see if these rumors of absolute paths working in windows are true.

Example:

`If you have your file at C:\somedir\antlib.xml then you want to write the following:  <taskdef resource="........" />`

or

Explain why this can't be done, please

Comment: What was the taskdef with the relative path please?

Comment: I'm not on Windows right now so I can't test it myself, but it could be a problem related to the use of forward slashes along with the drive letter. Try letting Ant resolve the path first by using the property task with the location attribute: `<property name="antlib.location" location="C:/path/to/antlib.xml" />` then pass it as a property: `<taskdef resource="${antlib.location}" />`

Comment: I know you're trying to remove the guesswork. I use absolute paths on Windows without issues, so I'm as much guessing as you. I wonder if it's to do with the length of the directory structure, or possibly the dots. Can you try popping the xml in just c:/dev and see if that works?

Comment: Please paste an example!  Thank you !!!  If you are not able to paste an example, at the very least please provide actionable information.  Do you use forward slashes?  Do you use a single backslash?  Do you use a double backslash?  Do you use a leading slash (of any kind) before the drive letter?

Comment: I use the exact Windows path, but replace the backslashes with forward slashes. Nothing else. I would change your example above to use a much simpler directory and play around with it.